# Как ограничить в классах-шаблонах передаваемый тип?

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Хочу создать класс шаблон:

```
template<typename T>
class myclass
{
  //...
}
```

Но при этом хочу, чтобы `T` было либо `int`, либо `double`, либо `float`.

Как в общем можно поставить ограничение такого вида на тип шаблона?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Современный метод — использовать `<type_traits>` и [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) (он вычисляется на этапе компиляции).

Например, ваше условие можно записать так:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class myclass
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<int, T>::value ||
        std::is_same<double, T>::value ||
        std::is_same<float, T>::value, 
        "T must be int, double or float"
    );
    //...
};
```

Пруф: http://ideone.com/VMXoi9

---

Загляните в `<type_traits>`, там есть много чего полезного.